# Deploy React project on a Windows server?

Tags: reactjs, windows, iis, deployment, hosting

I encountered an error while deploying an React build on a Windows server. To deploy a React project on a Windows server, you typically need to include a **web.config** file in the project's root directory and configure it with appropriate rules. This file helps IIS (Internet Information Services) understand how to handle requests and serve your React application correctly, especially if you are using client-side routing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Serve all files through index.html -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <!-- Enable gzip compression for faster page loads -->
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <!-- Serve SVG files with the correct MIME type -->
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Vague descriptions alone do not allow community members to understand the problem you are experiencing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please describe the problem you encountered in detail and provide relevant error information.

Comment: i'm not sure what the question is, but I suppose you have a conflict between react routing and your web server.

you need to delegate the routing management from your http server to you react app routing by redirecting all requests to the index.html file